# sqlplus connects to my Oracle server only on "second try"

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

My Oracle DB used to work fine but lately I have the following problem:

When I try to connect with sqlplus with a non-interactive command as the following, from the very machine I deployed my DB on,

```
sqlplus -L asd/mypass00@localhost/asddb
```

I get

```
SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Fri Mar 15 08:07:11 2024
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12537: TNS:connection closed


SP2-0751: Unable to connect to Oracle.  Exiting SQL*Plus
```

When I try to login interactively:

```
[oracle@localhost 19.3.0]$ sqlplus

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Fri Mar 15 08:14:58 2024
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: asd
Enter password:
Last Successful login time: Fri Mar 15 2024 07:59:45 +01:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0
```

Trying to connect from an external tool fails.

My env oracle variable are the following:

```
ORACLE_SID=asddb
ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle/product/19.3.0/
ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/19.3.0/
```

On the logs under /u01/app/oracle/product/19.3.0/diag/tnslsnr/myhostname/listener/alert/log.xml

After issuing

```
sqlplus -L asd/mypass00@localhost/asddb
```

I see the following log:

```
<msg time='2024-03-18T11:17:50.125+01:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='myhostname'
 host_addr='fe80::b698:10a:7057:3a57%enp0s31f6' pid='5743'>
 <txt>18-MAR-2024 11:17:50 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=asddb)(CID=(PROGRAM=sqlplus)(HOST=myhostname)(USER=oracle))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=38520)) * establish * asddb * 12518
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2024-03-18T11:17:50.125+01:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='myhostname'
 host_addr='fe80::b698:10a:7057:3a57%enp0s31f6' pid='5743'>
 <txt>TNS-12518: TNS:listener could not hand off client connection
 TNS-12547: TNS:lost contact
  TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
   TNS-00517: Lost contact
    Linux Error: 32: Broken pipe
 </txt>
</msg>
```

I am especially confused by the (USER=oracle) part, that I expected to be (USER=asd). I have no idea why sqlplus is fetching my current user name instead of the one provided in the CLI

Comment: that `USER` is your client osuser name, not the username you are logging in with. Since you are the local databse server, your client Unix user is `oracle`. The TNS string you see is the listener's registration of the source of the connection (client program, machine, osuser, and outgoing port), not the target (the database). If you are able to connect with bequeath (no `@`) but not with `@`, that means something is wrong with your listener, not your database.